# Flutter - Run Async Function for Each Listview Item

Tags: listview, geolocation, flutter

I have a list of locations I retrieve and display in a Listview Builder.

Each location has a latitude and longitude value.

Am now trying to include a "distance" field to the Listview using the GeoLocator Plugin (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/geolocator) - by having a "Find Nearest" button that gets the user location, then calculates the distance using the user's lat/lon and each location's lat/lon.

Since the "GeoLocator Calculate Distance Method" is asynchronous, I can't insert Geolocator().distanceBetween(userLat, 
userLon, storeLat, storeLon) directly into the widget.

QUESTION:
So how can I do it such that, when the user clicks on the button "Find Nearest", each Listview item is passed through the getDistance method and returns a result?

Simplified Code:

```
Future<List> getdata() async {
final response = await http.get(getStoreLocations);
return json.decode(response.body);
}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return new Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Location"),),
  body: new FutureBuilder<List>(
    future: getdata(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
      return snapshot.hasData
          ? new BrowseStoreLocation(
          list: snapshot.data,)
          : new Center(
        child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    },
  ),
);
}
}
```

GeoLocator Get User location Method:

```
getLocation () async {
Position position = await Geolocator().getCurrentPosition(LocationAccuracy.best);
userLat = position.latitude;
userLon = position.longitude;
setState(() {

});
}
```

GeoLocator Calculate Distance Method:

```
getDistance()async {
double distanceInMeters = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(userLat, 
userLon, storeLat, storeLon);
distance = distanceInMeters/1000;
}
```

I have tried experimenting by setting variables. The print displayed the storeLat and storeLon values for all items, but only the last listitem was calculated and returned.

```
String storeLat = "";
String storeLon = "";
getDistance(storeLat,storeLon)async {
double distanceInMeters = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(userLat, userLon, double.parse(storeLat), double.parse(storeLon));
distance = distanceInMeters/1000;
setState(() {
});
}

new ListView.builder(
itemCount: widget.list == null ? 0 : widget.list.length,
itemBuilder: (context, i) {
storeLat = widget.list[i]['latitude'];
storeLon = widget.list[i]['longitude'];
print(storeLon+storeLat);
return Container(
child: Column(
children: <Widget>[
new Text(distance.toString())
],
),
```

Comment: Hi Damien, did you found a solution? I'm having same issue in days... Don't know how to make a ListView item await the query

Comment: For me, I just had the Listview builder return a stateful class then had a Futurebuilder within here to run the async function for each listview item.

Comment: Can you please post that answer? I would really appreciate

Comment: If you found solution for this issue, can you please post it here. Thank you.

Comment: Was able to solve this with the help of this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60994455/flutter-looping-through-a-list-of-latitude-and-longitude-from-rest-api-to-get

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) for this purpose inside your [ListView.builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html) and then have to call your method `getDistance` inside that.

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: locationsList.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, position) {
    final current = locationsList[position];
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: getDistance(current.latitude, current.longitude)
                   .then((location) => location.toString()),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[new Text(snapshot.data)],
          ),
        );
     });
});
```