# How to get latitude and longtitude of coordinate stored on my database to await Geolocator().distanceBetween flutter

Tags: flutter, https

I am trying to get the distance between two locations. One of the locations is the user current location (currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude) and the other from stored location in my database (lat and lng). I am able to get user current location successful and also was able to fetch the latitude and longitude stored in my database but with below code, it only returns one out of the list of longitude and latitude.

```
String lat = "";
String lng = "";
Double distanceInKilometers = "";

Future getDistance() async {

    distanceInMeters = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(
        currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude, double.parse(lat), double.parse(lng));

    distanceInKilometers = distanceInMeters.toInt() / 1000;

    }


ListView.separated( itemCount: content.length,
                     itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                                      lat = content[position].lat;
                                      lng = content[position].lng;

                      return Container(
child: Column(
children: <Widget>[
new Text(distanceInKilometers.toString())
],
),
))
```

Comment: You should try to limit your code to the method you use and fails, for the sake of readability.

Comment: @i6x86 I just reduced the code. Please do you have a solution to this? Basically am fetching my latitude and longitude from my database and want to use it in my getDistance() to replace 25.1972 and 55.2744 respectively

Comment: where you are populating the currentLocation?

Comment: @Muhammed Noman I actually find a way around with this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/52359405/4940717 but am facing the same issue this person faced then. If you can help solve this on the link then am good

Comment: So, what error you get right now? Why you can't use the values?

Comment: when I used the method used on this link https://stackoverflow.com/q/52359405/4940717 only the last list item was calculated and returned

Comment: @MuhammadNoman any help yet?

Comment: @i6x86 any help too?

Comment: No offense intended, but I think yo should read how stack overflow works, how to ask questions etc... I understand you have a problem and need a help, but you can't ask something, then change your code over the fly and redirect us to other question. Also it's not good behaviour to ask everyone that post a comment if there's any solution yet. Here you have a good explanation how to use the comments https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work Despite that, can you, please, post your actual code and explain where it fails?

Comment: @i6x86 my sincere apology. I have edited the code to show my actual code and explained better where the error is.

Comment: I basically feel I need to add some kind of loop but not sure where and how. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I need your complete code to understand what you are actually doing

Comment: I just updated my code please kindly look at it again.

Comment: Was able to solve this with the help of this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60994455/flutter-looping-through-a-list-of-latitude-and-longitude-from-rest-api-to-get

Comment: Was able to solve this with the help of this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60994455/flutter-looping-through-a-list-of-latitude-and-longitude-from-rest-api-to-get