# Flutter - Looping through a list of latitude and longitude from rest api to get distance between two coordinates

Tags: dictionary, listview, flutter, distance

In my code being able to successfully get the distance between the two coordinate  (lAT and LNG)  but my listview returns the value for only one of the list of values. Kindly find my code below.

```
String lat = "";
String lng = "";
Double distanceInKilometers = "";

Future getDistance() async {

    distanceInMeters = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(
        currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude, double.parse(lat), double.parse(lng));

    distanceInKilometers = distanceInMeters.toInt() / 1000;

    }


ListView.separated( itemCount: content.length,
                     itemBuilder: (context, position) {
                                      lat = content[position].lat;
                                      lng = content[position].lng;

                      return Container(
child: Column(
children: <Widget>[
new Text(distanceInKilometers.toString())

],),

))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen multiple mistake in your code.

First, your code is not compiling

- `Double` type is lowercase in Dart language.
- You should not initialize a `double` variable with an empty `String`.

Second, you use global states with async calls. It would be better, if you just pass parameters into getDistance method. Like this:

```
Future<double> getDistance(double lat, double long) async {
  final distanceInMeters = await Geolocator().distanceBetween(
        currentLocation.latitude,
        currentLocation.longitude,
        lat,
        lng
  );

  return distanceInMeters / 1000;
}
```

Finally you should use a [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) to call `getDistance`:

```
ListView.separated(
  itemCount: content.length,
  separatorBuilder: (context, position) {
   // return a separator widget;
  },
  itemBuilder: (context, position) {
    final current = content[position];
    return FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: getDistance(current.lat, current.long)
                   .then((value) => value.toString()),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[new Text(snapshot.data)],
          ),
        );
     });
});
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is the problem? In my understanding, you get locations from a REST API, and you can list all location in a ListView, but every list item contains the same distance value. Is that right?

Comment: Thanks so much, @bvarga, I was able to figure where I got it wrong. Will like to ask how I can make sure of a progress indicator before it loads the distance. Also will like to know if there is another way to calculate driving distance btw two locations, cause when i refer the user to google map the distance shows a different figure from my calculate distance.